# Generic, optional type as an optional argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**How can I create an optional function argument who's type is generic?**

I have the following type definition:

```
type Ok<T> = { ok: true; value: T }
```

I want to write a function that combines the behavior of the two following functions into one:

```
const Ok = <T>(value: T): Ok<T> => {
    return { ok: true, value }
}
const Ok = (): Ok<undefined> => {
    return { ok: true, value: undefined }
}
```

- The argument is optional.
- If the argument is not included, then the generic type is `undefined`.
- If the argument is included, then the generic type is the type of the argument.

So you'd use the function like the following:

```
const emptyOk = Ok() // type Ok<undefined>
const okOne = Ok(1) // type Ok<number>
```

The end goal is to emulate Rust's `Result` type. I know there's several existing npm packages for emulating Rust's Result type. I'm looking to do something slightly different from any I found. I've also simplified things here to get to the root of my issue with TypeScript.

Comment: This sounds like a job for overloads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an overloaded function like this:

```
function Ok<T extends undefined>(value?: T): Ok<T>
function Ok<T>(value: T): Ok<T>;
function Ok<T>(value: T): Ok<T> {
    return { ok: true, value }
}
```

The overload for the `undefined` type prevents type issues caused by allowing the property to always be undefined.

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/mqY0Jm